# EF 4.1 code first still looking for old table that no longer exists

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 code first.

I had a table in the database with the name `MaritalStatus`.  I deleted it and created a new table in its place called `MaritalStatuses`.  Whenever I try to get all the records from the table I get an error:

**Invalid object name 'dbo.MaritalStatus'.**

The query that it is trying to execute is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive]
FROM [dbo].[MaritalStatus] AS [Extent1]}
```

Why would it still be looking for table MaritalStatus that I deleted?  Can it be possible that it is cached somewhere?  I dropped the whole database and recreated it via scripts.  Still no luck.  Maybe it has an issue when it comes to the "es" part of the name?

Context class:

```
public class HefContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
   public DbSet<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

View model (with partial properties):

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int MaritalStatusId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
   public int BankId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
   public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Dropdown list in view for MaritalStatuses:

```
<td><label>Marital Status:</label> <span class="red">**</span></td>
<td>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MaritalStatusId, new SelectList(Model.MaritalStatuses, "Id", "Name", Model.MaritalStatusId), "-- Select --")
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MaritalStatusId)
</td>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   EditGrantApplicationViewModel viewModel = new EditGrantApplicationViewModel
   {
      MaritalStatuses = maritalStatusService.GetAll(),
      Banks = bankService.GetAll(),
      AccountTypes = accountTypeService.GetAll()
   };

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

Service:

```
public IEnumerable<MaritalStatus> GetAll()
{
   return maritalStatusRepository.GetAll();
}
```

Repository:

```
HefContext db = new HefContext();

public IEnumerable<MaritalStatus> GetAll()
{
   return db.MaritalStatuses;
}
```

Model class:

```
public class MaritalStatus
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have renamed the table in your database, but your Model class is still tied to the old name. You need to map the entity to the desired table name in the OnModelCreating method of your DbContext object

```
public class HefContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
   public DbSet<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<MaritalStatus>().ToTable("MaritalStatuses");
   }
}
```

**Update:**

Apparently EF code first has some issues with the pluralization of some table names, such as Status. Out of curiosity I tested a few others and found several which also had this same issue.

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  Look at my context class, Banks and AccountTypes and mapped to the Banks and AccountTypes.  Why would this be any different?

Comment: perhaps there is a bug in the pluralization of the entity MaritalStatus. The table names are generated based off of your entity, not the property name on your DbContext

Comment: It must be then because it knows that Bank must be mapped to Banks and that AccountType must be linked to AccountTypes.  But it just doesn't know that MaritalStatus must be mapped to MaritalStatuses.  Maybe it has an issue when it comes to the "es" part of the name?

Comment: I added a property and tables called Addresses.  This worked fine.  Then I added a new one called AddressStatuses and then it was also looking for AddressStatus (in plural form).  Not sure what is happening here when using the word ..Statuses?  So I changed the table to MaritalStatusTypes and it works fine now.

Comment: Which other names did you have issues with?  Where did you read this online?  I only found words ending in Status has errors.

Answer (score -2):

I guess this is wrong:

```
public DbSet<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
```

Should be:

```
public DbSet<MaritalStatuses> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why did you change MaritalStatus to MaritalStatuses? The name of the model class is MaritalStatus.

Comment: EF will try to create the objectset based on a MaritalStatus database object, refactor the code to reflect the new name.

Comment: From the metadata: public T CreateObject<T>() where T : class;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity> instance that is used
        //     to query, add, modify, and delete objects of the specified entity type.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   TEntity:
        //     Entity type of the requested System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity>.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The new System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<TEntity> instance.
        //

Comment: It is supposed to do that when I define my entity sets.  It's the same name as the new table so I'm not sure why I need to add additional configuration.

Comment: Your database has a table MaritalStatuses, but you tell EF to look for MaritalStatus

Comment: I have tables called Banks and AccountTypes as well.  The other 2 properties in the context knows that it must link to these 2 tables.